# Bootstrap Input with datalist dropdown doesn´t work on iPhone (6s)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I wrote a simple `HTML5` / `Javascript` application. 
I used the `bootstrap3` (`js` & `css`).
The app itself should be mobile friendly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

On mobile devices the look & feel is as designed, except for one issue:
I am using inputs (inside a `.well`) with datalists like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="userIdType">Type:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userIdType"  list = "lst_userIdTypes" value="AD_ID"> 
                  <datalist id="lst_userIdTypes">
                    <option>AD_ID</option>
                    <option>PU_ID</option>
                    <option>XU_ID</option>
                    <option>DE_ID</option>
                    <option>AP_ID</option>
                  </datalist>
                </div>
```

The list works fine on Android 5.x phones with chrome and firefox browser.

But on my iPhone (6s) in safari and chrome browser the values of the list don´t show.
Is this a known issue? Does anybody know how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To all who are still looking: this amazing workaround saved me.
It is an editable select via JS which has the same functionality as input + datalist
https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select

Answer (score 1):

According to w3schools, Safari does not support datalist tag even though that is part of the HTML5 standard.

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Chrome on iPhone also uses mainly the same engine as Safari since Apple does not enables 3rd party browser engines on their OS. That is why you experienced the same behavior from both browsers on iPhone.

No other solutions, than workarounds can be used in this case.